# Spring JPA reference a table with other table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating a quiz game in Spring using JPA and I've created the user already, now I'm creating the question and answer, the thing is question must have at least 1 answer because it can contains two corrects, my doubt is how do I create the tables to do this?

This is my Question class

```
@Entity(name = "question")
public class Question extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Question name can not be blank")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_exam_question", nullable = false)
    private Boolean is_exam_question;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Here I'm missing something because I want to know which user has answered the question and how many times has he succeed or not.

Also my Answer class is

```
@Entity(name = "answer")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answer_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "answer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "answer_to_question")
    @NotBlank(message = "Answer to question name can not be blank")
    private String answer_to_question;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;
}
```

### Explained better

How do I add multiple answer to questions and how do I assign this answer to a question?

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple-choice question and answers or simple question with 2 possible answers which user will type?

Comment: Let's say the teacher can create a question and can assign to it different answers to this question. Is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class name as Quiz.class

```java
@Entity
public class Quiz{

@Id
private int id;

private String quizName;

private String quizDescription;

private int passingScore;

private int totalScore;

// Getter and setters
}
```

Question.class will look like this

```java
@Entity(name = "question")
public class Question extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Question name can not be blank")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_exam_question", nullable = false)
    private Boolean is_exam_question;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },mappedBy="question")
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Quiz quiz;

}
```

Tests.class will look like this

```java
@Entity
public class Tests{

private int id;

@ManyToOne
private Quiz quiz;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

private int score;

private String status; // failed or passed

}
```

I think this will help you. Feel free to ask me more Questions.

Comment: The thing is that I have two diferent types of quiz (at the moment)... Teacher can create a solo quiz means that all the questions has type of is_exam_type = false, exam quiz which contains all the questions with is_exam_type = true, you got me?

Comment: You have to Define type in main entity of `Quiz.class`

Comment: Thanks, and regarding this question ? "I want to know which user has answered the question and how many times has he succeed or not."

Comment: From where I can contact you Muhammad? I'd like to ask you something